# UITableView like NSTableView

Tags: macos, uitableview, nstableview

Ive developed for iOS  in the past and recently moved over to mac development. I began a project to "get the feel" of things, and ran into an issue. Im trying to create a NSTableView to display multiple items, including a label, a 2 UIImageViews, and a UIButton. NSTableViews are way different than tables on iOS, and I cant simply create a custom TableViewCell (I think). A great example of how I would like it to look is AlienBlue for Mac: (The middle table with post information)

[image: AlienBlue for Mac]

Can anyone shed some light on how to create this?

Comment: I think the title of this post needs a hyphen: "UITableView-like NSTableView". Or "NSTableView like UITableView".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the power of being able to return whole views instead of cells in NSTableViews.

Here's [Apple's documentation on View-based tables](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [how to populate those views in your table](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html).

The delegate method I use most in my own view-based tables is ["`tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:)

Hopefully this points you in the right direction!

Comment: Unfortunately the links in the answer doesn't seem to be available now. :(

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

Please use NSCollectionView instead (set NSCollectionView.maxNumberOfColumns = 1).  It's a more modern, extensible view api, that is analogous to UICollectionView.

In contrast, NSTableView was originally meant for displaying a spreadsheet table (with add-on support for custom view cells), and is less consistent with UITableView.